# FreeMarker special character output as question mark

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, freemarker, iso-8859-15

I am trying to submit a form with fields containing special characters, such as `€ŠšŽžŒœŸ`. As far as I can see from the [ISO-8859-15 wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15), these characters are included in the standard. Even though the encoding for both request and response is set to the ISO-8859-15, when I am trying to display the values (using FreeMarker 2.3.18 in a JAVA EE environment), the values are `???????`. I have set the form's accepted charset to `ISO-8859-15`, I have checked that the form is submitted with content-type `text/html;charset=ISO-8859-15` (using firebug) but I can't figure out how to display the correct characters. If I am running the following code, the correct hex value is displayed `(ex: Ÿ = be)`.

What am I missing? Thank you in advance!

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(myString.charAt(i)));
```

**EDIT:**

I am having the following code as I process the request:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "ISO-8859-15");
String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");

// check for null before
for (int i = 0; i < firstName.length(); i++) {
     ps.println(firstName.charAt(i)); // prints "?"
}

BufferedWriter file=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path), "ISO-8859-15"));
file.write(firstName); // writes "?" to file (checked with notepad++, correct encoding set) 
file.close();
```

Comment: I have a freemarker/spring/tomcat environment. Mine displays a question mark and is sent as a question mark over the network, however, I have FM set up to output to a StringWriter first and at this point the original character is still Ÿ, so my guess is that the problem occurs after FM has processed the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the hex value, the form data is submitted correctly.
The problem seems to be related to the output. Java replaces a character with `?` if it cannot be represented with the charset in use.

You have to use a correct charset when constructing the output stream. What commands do you use for that? I do not know FreeMarker but there will probably be something like

```
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
```

This should be replaced with something resembling this:

```
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "iso-8859-15");
```

By the way, UTF-8 is usually much better choice for the encoding charset.

Comment: I have tried using this in a small project and it worked. There was no encoding specified. Thank you!